# Can't open files saved using windows long path workaround

Tags: python, windows, filesystems

I am saving matplotlib figures `savefig(filename)` from my python script using an absolute path, which is very long.

I had problems with max path length limitation on windows `Errno2 no such file or directory`, so I started appending `\\?\` to the beginning of the path and it seemed to work.

However, some of my saved figures seem to be corrupted, as I try to open them with windows default image viewer and it just closes without showing the image. Some other figures saved by the exactly same procedure worked fine though.

I have noticed that the figures that do not open have the `\\?\` appended to the location property in the windows explorer file property dialog:

[image: property dialog]

The ones working does not have it:

[image: peoperty dialog 2]

EDIT:

I found new information: When the whole *absolute path + filename* has 260 characters or more (without the `\\?\` in the beginning), then I get this corrupted behavior and can't open my file.

EDIT 2:

I tried creating a text file (with `open(filename,'wb'`) instead of saving a matplotlib figure. I get the same `\\?\` in the location propert and when I try to open it this is what I get:

[image: text popup]

So basically the `\\?\` allows me to create a figure or textfile, but I cannot open it anyway.

EDIT 3 - well it turns out the files are not corrupted, as I can move them to a folder closer to root and they can be opened with no problems.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you just move your program to a shorter path and run it there?

Comment: Are you saying that some figures do have `"\\?\"` and others not? In any case, I don't think one can further investigate this without a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest exactly. I will try to have a very minimal example to post here.

Comment: What I mean is rather that if every file that has `"\\?\"` prepended to its path does not open, the seamingly working solution of using  `"\\?\"` might not even work at all. But, yes, provide a  [mcve], such that people can actually look at this.

Comment: No no, actually I have appended this to the filename string of all of my saved pictures. However, some are fine (and show no signal of the \\?\ in the windows explorer dialog), and others are corrupted (and show it on the property dialog)

Comment: "\\?\" tells Windows to bypass path normalization, except to replace "\\?\" with "\??\", i.e. NT's virtual directory for DOS devices. Object paths that start with "\??" are generally parsed by checking the local DOS devices for the caller's logon session, found in "\Sessions\0\DosDevices\<logonId>". This object directory in turn has a "Global" object symbolic link to the "\Global??" directory in which system DOS devices are defined. For example, DOS drive "C:" is "\Global??\C:", which is a symlink to a numbered volume device such as "\Device\HarddiskVolume2".

Comment: The Windows shell and some applications generally don't work with "\\?\" extended paths. They were written for the `MAX_PATH` (260) limit inherited from DOS, back in the days of Windows 9x. The shell is gradually getting updated to support long paths in Windows 10, and in many cases long paths now work without using the "\\?\" prefix. It's still required to bypass DOS normalization rules such as stripping trailing spaces and dots, or acting as if every directory contains DOS devices such as "CON" and "COM1".